# Best way to Migrate Anonymous Profile

Tags: asp.net, profiling, anonymous, migrate

Is there an alternate way that migrates all parameters implicit? Or any other advantages.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewfkf772.aspx):

```
public void Profile_OnMigrateAnonymous(object sender, ProfileMigrateEventArgs args)
{
  ProfileCommon anonymousProfile = Profile.GetProfile(args.AnonymousID);

  Profile.ZipCode = anonymousProfile.ZipCode;
  Profile.CityAndState = anonymousProfile.CityAndState;
  Profile.StockSymbols = anonymousProfile.StockSymbols;

  ////////
  // Delete the anonymous profile. If the anonymous ID is not 
  // needed in the rest of the site, remove the anonymous cookie.

  ProfileManager.DeleteProfile(args.AnonymousID);
  AnonymousIdentificationModule.ClearAnonymousIdentifier(); 

  // Delete the user row that was created for the anonymous user.
  Membership.DeleteUser(args.AnonymousID, true);

}
```

Or is this the best/only way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the way to go. But I would suggest a generalization. Instead of hardcoding each property you could loop through the [ProfileBase.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.properties.aspx) collection. Something along these lines:

```
var anonymousProfile = Profile.GetProfile(args.AnonymousID);
foreach(var property in anonymousProfile.PropertyValues)
{
    Profile.SetPropertyValue(property.Name, property.PropertyValue);
}
```

Since property groups are represented as part of the property names (e.g. "Settings.Theme" represents the Theme property within the Settings group) the above code should also work with property groups.

Comment: Would this also take groups of properties?

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand your question correctly?

Migrating Profile Properties During Log On

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e.aspx

Comment: Yes, But this the only way to do it?
Is there, let's say a more implicit way to migrate?