# Anonymous Identification in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, anonymousidentification

In the previous ASP.NET MVC, you can turn on the anonymous identification easily by adding 1 line in your `web.config`:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
```

We can use the anonymous identification, i.e., `Request.AnonymousID` to identify unauthenticated users on your site. This is pretty useful for eCommerce experience when you need to save the items in the shopping cart against visitors.

More info in: http://www.toplinestrategies.com/blogs/net/anonymous-identification-mvc

**The Problem:**

`Request.AnonymousID` comes from `System.Web`, and it's gone with ASP.NET Core.

**Questions:**

1. How can we enable anonymous identification in ASP.NET Core MVC?
2. If 1 is not possible, how would you "identify" visitors on your site?

**Note:** I don't want to use Sessions to store objects.

Comment: I don't have any .NET Core project that needs this needs yet. Have you tried to create a cookie with GUID value each time when the application starts up, and delete/refresh that cookie after the user logs out? `Request.AnonymousID` from `System.Web` is just a GUID. This is what I can think of for now (why am I answering my own question :))

Answer (score 6):

I coded a solution on my own. It is a middleware for ASP.NET Core that mimics the old behavior.

You can find the package on NuGet as [AnonymousId (ReturnTrue.AspNetCore.Identity.Anonymous)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReturnTrue.AspNetCore.Identity.Anonymous) and the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/aleripe/AnonymousId).

I'm new to the whole world of ASP.NET Core so please let me know of any bug, improvement, advice, correction...

The basic usage is:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseAnonymousId();
    ....
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ViewResult Index()
  {
      string anonymousId = Request.Headers["AnonymousId"];
      ....
  }
}
```